# How helm-chart can subscribe aArgoCD notification webhook

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd, argocd-notification

I have added trigger, template & webhook in configmap argocd-notifications-cm using folowing command:

> kubectl edit cm argocd-notofications-cm -n argocd

The webhook is added like below:

`service.webhook.mapper: | url: http://<IP>:<Port>`

template is added like below:

`template.mapping: | webhook: mapper: method: POST path: /post body: | { "xx": "yy"}`

trigger is added like below:

`trigger.on-sync-succeeded: |

- description: abc
  send:

  - mapping:
    when: app.status.operationState.phase in ['Succeeded']`

I am deploying the application in ArgoCD using ApplicationSet object & helmchart. The directory structure is like be below inside root directory of github repo:

`apps/app1/templates/.. apps/app1/chart apps/app1/Chart.yaml apps/app1/Values.yaml`

`argo-cd/argo_cd.yaml #Application Object arco_cd/apps.yaml    # ApplicationSet argo_cd/httpbin.yaml # Application`

In both Application & ApplicationSet objects, syncpolicy is like following:

`syncPolicy: automated: selfHeal: true prune: true` 
Now question is how "apps" or "app1" will subscribe so that any sync success of app1 will send the POST request to httpbin?

I tried it by adding annotation under metadata of apps.yaml ApplicationSet object. But no notification is received.